# Display Android mobile application on the list of options in Settings menu of mobile browser

Tags: android

I have the following requirement:

i> User opens a web page in mobile browser of device.

ii> The web page contains a Download button (for file download)

iii> User clicks on the Menu button of the device . Options like Back , Add bookmark , More , etc.  On click of More provides the option like Home , Page info , Share page , etc.

iv>On click of Share page , list of applications are displayed . e.g: Bluetooth , Gmail , Mail

First of all , I want my Android application to be displayed on the list of applications.

Next , when the user clicks on the my Android application , I need to take the user to a specific screen from where the user can Upload the files to a different file server location which are currently available on the webpage for download.

i> How can I add my Android application to the list of options ?

ii> How to navigate the user to a specific screen of the application ?

iii> How to get the file download link so that the file is first downloaded to a temp folder on the SDCard ?

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions. You'll probably get more and better answers if you split them up into separate questions. Meanwhile I suggest you read up [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4669627/741249) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3526700/741249) which will answer your first question.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all , I want my Android application to be displayed on the list of applications.

Implement an activity with the following `<intent-filter>`:

```
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

> How can I add my Android application to the list of options ?

You asked this already.

> How to navigate the user to a specific screen of the application ?

You asked this already, as "screen" == "activity" in Android (at least in your scenario).

> How to get the file download link so that the file is first downloaded to a temp folder on the SDCard ?

You cannot "get the file download link", because the user did not click the "file download link".

Comment: Thanks for the reply . using the above intent-filter parameters, I created the apk file . The apk got installed on the device but the application is not visible on the device Menu option . The application can be viewed only from list of applications displayed from the Settings Share page menu. The following were the default parameters I was using before I added the new parameters provided by you. <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                     Is it possible to have both the actions?

Comment: @chiranjib: "The application can be viewed only from list of applications displayed from the Settings Share page menu." -- of course. That is all you can do.

Comment: I viewed one Android application which is displayed both on the mobile device Menu & also Settings Share page menu ... Name of the application: YouSendIt . Any idea how similar functionality can be implemented using the IntentFilter parameters ? Anyways thanks a lot .

Comment: @chiranjib: YouSendIt has nothing in its manifest other than a standard MAIN/LAUNCHER activity, the SEND activity that I outlined in my answer, and a bunch of private activities.