# Sending an Intent from Google Maps to an Android app with geo information

Tags: android, google-maps

I'd like to send Intent from Google Maps to the Android app I'm developing, that would include geo information (latitude, longitude, etc).

I know it requires setting up an intent filter, however the only one I got working so far is the plain/text one:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This however only gives me textual description looking like this:

```
899 Green St, San Francisco, CA 94133, https://goo.gl/maps/R4A82MNvUpA2
```

I've experimented with the below, however that didn't work (the intent wasn't even registered in Google Maps):

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm using Android 9 (Pie).

Comment: when do want to send the intent?

Comment: When the share button is pressed

Comment: Take a look on my detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75021893/3090951

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar problem and I found a way.

use geocoding to get location data:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=899+Green+St,+San+Francisco,+CA+94133&key=your_key

you will the lat and lng with a bunch of other data:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "899",
                    "short_name": "899",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Green Street",
                    "short_name": "Green St",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Russian Hill",
                    "short_name": "Russian Hill",
                    "types": [
                        "neighborhood",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "San Francisco",
                    "short_name": "SF",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "San Francisco County",
                    "short_name": "San Francisco County",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "California",
                    "short_name": "CA",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "94133",
                    "short_name": "94133",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "899 Green St, San Francisco, CA 94133, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 37.7989435,
                        "lng": -122.4128121
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 37.7982939,
                        "lng": -122.4138552
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.7988047,
                    "lng": -122.4131897
                },
                "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 37.79996768029149,
                        "lng": -122.4119846697085
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 37.7972697197085,
                        "lng": -122.4146826302915
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJrd0tGO6AhYARxCp3djZ6Ka0",
            "types": [
                "premise"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: An overview about Place IDs: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

Comment: hey @Sean what happens to the bounty if grace period is over and he has not accepted my answer.??