# Plan a route in Google maps on phone, then share it to another app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I have found a way to intercept an intent and share a route from Google maps to my Android app, like described here:
[How to add your application to the "share this place" list in Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526700/how-to-add-your-application-to-the-share-this-place-list-in-google-maps)

The problem is, that this content is plan text.

I could not find a way to get an API URL, which would return me the legs and steps, like I get, when making the call on the API URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json

The possibly "valuable" content of this plain text data is this URL:
https://goo.gl/maps/ABkChYmCLruqemju9

But I think this is also not so valuable, because the text beside it states:
"For the best route in current traffic visit".

I would like to be able to plan a route in Maps, then interact with it, in my application.

I have also been reading about the option of exporting to KML, but I think that is not doable on Android mobile apps?

What options do I have?

The information on this is so sparse and vague, I almost believe there is no way, but that is also hard to believe, for something like this...

Comment: Do you want to create a route in Maps SDK for Android?  You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/get-driving-directions-using-google-maps-api-v2) if this is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but no. I want to plan a route in the Maps application, which I can then import into my app, as an intent.